# Different memoization techniques in Ruby

Tags: ruby, performance, memoization

If you are a ruby programmer then you might have come across the hash block memoization pattern. For a simple example I present you the memoized version of the Fibonacci sequence:

```
fib_hash = Hash.new do |h,i|
  h[i] = h[i-1] + h[i-2]
end
# establish the base cases
fib_hash[1] = 1; fib_hash[2] = 1
```

Of course this is not the only way to create a memoized version of the Fibonacci sequence. You could also do the following:

```
@cache = {}; @cache[1] = 1; @cache[2] = 1
def memo_fib(n)
  @cache[n] ||= (memo_fib(n-1) + memo_fib(n-2))
end
```

Hopefully you see how the hash block memoization pattern maps to the second version which is much more common in many other languages. What I would like to know is if there is any difference between the two versions? I can't shake the feeling that the hash block version is more efficient but I can't really justify why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A benchmark in MRI 1.8.7 yields:

- Hash block: 0.44 seconds
- Non hash block: 0.41 seconds

And in MRI 1.9.0:

- Hash block: 0.24 seconds
- Non hash block: 0.28 seconds

The benchmark is 100 iterations of computing the Fibonacci numbers from 1 through 1000, resetting the hash or cache at the start of each iteration.

Here's the benchmark for the hash block:

```
def reset_fib_hash                                                              
  @fib_hash = Hash.new do |h,i|
    h[i] = h[i-1] + h[i-2]
  end
  # establish the base cases                                                    
  @fib_hash[1] = 1; @fib_hash[2] = 1
end

start_time = Time.now
100.times do
  reset_fib_hash
  (1..1000).each do |i|
    @fib_hash[i]
  end
end
p Time.now - start_time
```

Here's the benchmark for the non hash block:

```
def reset_fib_hash
  @cache = {}; @cache[1] = 1; @cache[2] = 1
end

def memo_fib(n)
  @cache[n] ||= (memo_fib(n-1) + memo_fib(n-2))
end

start_time = Time.now
100.times do
  reset_fib_hash
  (1..1000).each do |i|
    memo_fib(i)
  end
end
p Time.now - start_time
```

Comment: So method calls are cheaper than block calls.Good to know, thanks.

Comment: Actually I did a test on the 1.9.1 ruby version and the hash block version was faster.

Comment: @davidk01, Shame on me for not saying which version I tested.  As you probably guessed, it was 1.8.7.  I've added MRI 1.9.0 results to the answer.